# FB.Data.query and SSL

Tags: facebook, api

I'm using FB.Data.query for a user registration page. The page uses an SSL cert and one of the items I need to get from facebook is the user's photo. However when I grab this it give me the HTTP link but I need the HTTPS link. I know that you can user return_ssl_resources = 1, but I'm not sure how that goes into my code. Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code.

var query = FB.Data.query('select username, first_name, last_name, email, about_me, current_location, meeting_sex, sex, pic_square, pic_big, birthday_date from user where uid={' + zero + '}', my_facebook_id);

Answer (score 0):

return_ssl_resources is deprecated as far as I know.  I don't know if you can get the HTTPS profile picture via FQL, but if you just get the basic user information via the graph api over HTTPS, it will return an HTTPS profile pic URL that you can add ?type=large to make it the large pic.

Comment: I don’t think it’s deprecated; at least the docs still describe it without mentioning anything about deprecation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#pictures